# Need an example of boost-geometry rtree with geographic coordindates and nearest query

Tags: boost-geometry

I need to store geographic points in rtree and be able to answer nearest query.

Can someone provide an example similar to [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/rtree_examples/quick_start.html) but with point type  `bg::model::point<float, 2, bg::cs::geographic<bg::degree>>`? Is that supported?

Comment: Did you try? What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is only partially implemented in boost 1.65.1. If you use geographic points please make sure that you use at least 1.67 or so. Boost.Geometry changed significantly since 1.65.